# Mercurial does not know if there is a repo or not

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am in my first days of Mercurial, I did my google homework, but I can't find a solution to this.

Here is the output from the server which should explain things better than I could:

```
david@triton:~/www/triton$ ls -l -a | grep .hg
drwxr-xr-x  4 david david 4096 2011-11-19 17:44 .hg
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    0 2011-11-18 22:23 .hgignore
david@triton:~/www/triton$ hg init
abort: repository . already exists!
david@triton:~/www/triton$ hg serve
abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!
```

I am trying to push from tortiseHG on a windows client to this server but it too is complaining about there being no repo.

What the heck, guys?

Comment: Have you made any commits to the repo yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if the versions of mercurial differ between server and client. In that case you'll have to convert the repo to the older version (or upgrade your client to the server version) in order to fix the issue. HTH!

If you run a hg stat or hg summary like R4yan said, you might see a more helpful error message. If it's a difference in version you might see something like: 'abort: requirement 'dotencode' not supported!'

Answer (score 5):

`hg init` is just checking if a `.hg` directory already exists, which it clearly does.  Try

```
$ ls -l .hg
ls: cannot access .hg: No such file or directory
$ mkdir .hg
$ hg init
abort: repository . already exists!
```

How did that `.hg` directory get there?  If you created it yourself, you shouldn't have. You should have let `hg init` create it as it puts a lot of other stuff in there.  What output do you get from `hg summary`?